# "is risky TO you" vs. "is risky FOR you"

Tags: prepositions

Could anyone clarify to me the difference between **for** and **to** in this context? Are these two prepositions interchangeable in this phrase?

> Going out during the pandemic would be really risky **TO** you?
>
> Going out during the pandemic would be really risky **FOR** you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll illustrate the difference with another example:

> This seems risky **to me**. → This seems risky **in my opinion**. (it may or may not affect me)
>
> This seems risky **for me**. → This seems risky **for me personally**. (I am affected by it)

So the question:

> Would going out during the pandemic be risky **to** you?

is asking for an opinion - do you think it's a risky idea to try and go out? Whereas the question:

> Would going out during the pandemic be risky **for** you?

is asking whether you would be at risk risk if you go out.